# Gitlab CI - is there a difference between a rule with when:always to a rule without?

Tags: if-statement, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, rules

I have a pipeline in Gitlab-CI and one of the jobs has the rule:

```
rules:
  - if: "$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
```

Will there be a difference if I will change it to:

```
  - if: "$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    when: always
```

Because, the first rule will execute when the condition is met
and the alternative rule ( the one with the when: always ) will do the same thing.

So what is the "when: always" will change? if it will change anything at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. By default, the value of `when:` is `on_success` -- jobs only run if jobs in previous stages succeed. Using `always` will allow the job to run, even if jobs in the previous stage failed.

Per [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#when) these are the possible values for `when`:

> `on_success` (default): Run the job only when all jobs in earlier stages succeed or have allow_failure: true.
> `manual`: Run the job only when triggered manually.
> `always`: Run the job regardless of the status of jobs in earlier stages.   Can also be used in workflow:rules.
> `on_failure`: Run the job only when at least one job in an earlier stage fails. A job with allow_failure: true is always considered successful.
> `delayed`: Delay the execution of a job for a specified duration.
> `never`: Don’t run the job. Can only be used in a rules section or workflow: rules.

But if you did the following, it would be effectively the same as the first example:

```yaml
  - if: "$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    when: on_success
```

This also assumes `when:` is not used in the job body.

If you do have `when:` in the body AND in your rules, this changes a bit.

```yaml
myjob:
  when: always
  rules:
    - if: ...
      when: on_success  # this takes precedence if this rule matches
    - if: ...  # uses the default "when:" if this rule matches
```

In which case, adding the `when:` to the rules, the `when:` specified in the rules will take precedence over the `when:` set in the job body when the rule matches.

In older versions of GitLab, mixing `job:when:` and `job:rules:when:` is not allowed and results in an error.

Comment: is there any option like 
  - if: always

or
  - if: true
I couldn't find a flag that returns always true.

Comment: @ÖmerGÜZEL `- if: $CI` should always evaluate true.